# Pass value through template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular and ui-router for my templating.

This is the routing for this part,

```
.state('home.container-big',{
  url: '',
  views: {
    "container-big":{
      templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_movie-info.html',
      controller: 'addMovieCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('home.container-big.container-big-trailer',{
  url: '',
  views: {
    "youtube_trailer":{
      templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_container-trailer.html'
    }
  }
})
```

When my `home.container-big` state is loaded it injects the `__movie-info.html.haml` template into the `container-big` view.

```
.container-info
  %ul.trailers
    %li{"ng-repeat" => "trailer in filteredTrailers = (trailers | filter: { movie_id: movie.movie_id})"}
      %a{:href => "#", "value" => "{{ trailer.link }}", "ui-sref" => ".container-big-trailer"} Load trailer

.container-trailers
    %div{"ui-view" => "youtube_trailer"}
```

This template has another template injection, when a user clicks on `Load trailer` it loads the `home.container-big.container-big-trailer` state and injects the template `_container-trailer.html.haml` in the `youtube_trailer` view.

```
%youtube{:videoid => "value from clicked link"}
```

What I want to do is when a user clicks `Load template` pass the value of the `<a href>` clicked from the `_movie-info` template into the `_container-trailer` template.

Here's a clearer example,

`_movie-info.html.haml` template,

```
<div class="container-info">
  <ul class="trailers">
    <li><a href="#", value="KlyknsTJk0w", ui-sref=".container-big-trailer">Load trailer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#", value="nyc6RJEEe0U", ui-sref=".container-big-trailer">Load trailer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#", value="zSWdZVtXT7E", ui-sref=".container-big-trailer">Load trailer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#", value="Lm8p5rlrSkY", ui-sref=".container-big-trailer">Load trailer</a></li> <-- clicked element 
    <li><a href="#", value="ePbKGoIGAXY", ui-sref=".container-big-trailer">Load trailer</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div ui-view="youtube_trailer"></div> <-- here the _container-trailer is injected
```

`_container-trailer.html.haml`

```
<youtube videoid="Lm8p5rlrSkY"></youtube>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a parameter in your state definition:

```
$stateProvider.state(..., {
    params: {
        value: null
    }
});
```

Then you can send optional parameters with `ui-sref`:

```
<a value="KlyknsTJk0w" ui-sref=".container-big-trailer({value: KlyknsTJk0w})">Load trailer</a>
```

Now if you inject `$stateParams` into the controller and retreive your value:

```
function ($scope,   $stateParams) {
    $scope.value = $stateParams.value;
}
```

Reference: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

Example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/bSy6ezIJZshKSFFs298M?p=preview

Comment: You also need the `value` parameter in the state's `url` for it to populate `$stateParams`

Comment: Not exactly but ok, you'll need to defined a param indeed, but it doesn't have to be in the URL, appended to my answer. thnx!

Comment: Didn't know you could pass non-url params via `ui-sref`. Wouldn't survive a page refresh but still nice to know :)

Comment: Opted to go with this answer for a slighty cleaner URL. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Make it part of the state and assign the parameter to the controller scope (or controller instance if you're using *"controller as"*)

```
.state('home.container-big.container-big-trailer',{
  url: '/:videoId',
  views: {
    "youtube_trailer":{
      templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_container-trailer.html',
      controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
        $scope.videoId = $stateParams.videoId;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Then your `_container-trailer.html` can use

```
<youtube videoid="{{videoId}}"></youtube>
```

and you pass the params like this

```
<a ui-sref=".container-big-trailer({videoId: 'Lm8p5rlrSkY'})">Load trailer</a>
```

Comment: So in the state definition you can make your own mini controller and have it act as the controller for that template. That's pretty cool thanks, going to try it out.

Comment: I used this code and it worked great, but it did clutter the URL a bit, so opted to go with the answer above. But thanks for the input!